# Easy way to determine what what functions from a package are used by a dependent package?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, source

I'm working on stripping a system to the least amount of files, packages, etc.. that it needs to provide the functionality I desire.

I'm finding that a lot of packages I would like to keep have dependencies on packages which are completely unnecessary, and/or unwanted for the distribution I'm building, aside from the fact that they are dependencies.

I know that I can pull the source for each package, compile a list of functions from the unwanted dependency, scan the source of the package I want to keep for where those functions are called (if at all), and strip the library to just that function and possibly it's api, or whatever else is necessary to deliver that functionality to the package I would like to keep.

I've now done this, ***once*** to see if it was possible. It is. However it's time-consuming, tedious, and hardly a candidate for automation.

Is there an option I haven't been able to find in `dpkg` or a program that exists that has escaped my (admittedly not amazing) research abilities to achieve my desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`deborphan`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/deborphan) attempts to solve this problem.

`aptitude` does it for you behind the scenes, keeping track of which packages can be removed because they were pulled in merely to satisfy a dependency for a package which is no longer installed.

[`debfoster`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debfoster) advertises somewhat similar functionality, but I don't have practical experience with it.

These all work on the package level, and use the declared dependencies in `dpkg`'s database.  Your question seems to suggest that you want to strip down individual packages to remove code and other resources which you don't need.  This is a significantly more complex and demanding task; I don't imagine anything cut and dried exists to solve this problem.

Comment: `deborphan` is beautiful. Perfect for isolating packages which don't have deps. I guess I was looking to get, perhaps a bit excessive with the optimization and determine the extent of, and potentially excise small functionality from a larger dependency... But on second thought, it prohibits my ability to get critical updates for any of the packages I would mangle in the process.

Comment: `debfoster` is great too. Has more robust output, and is interactive. You're right about the intent. I'm putting the endeavor on the back-burner for the time being. Low-hanging fruit and all that. Great recommendations.